# How to copy the output of pexpect to a file

Tags: python, pexpect

What I expect are:

1. the output of pexpect can be displayed in the terminal in real time, so that I can see the real-time progress of the script execution.
2. the output of pexpect can be **copied** to a file, so that the log
   can be automatically managed.

I know how to display the results on the terminal and how to redirect the results to a file, but I don’t know how to implement these two features at the same time.

Below is my sample code：

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# !/usr/bin/python3

import pexpect
import time
import sys

username = 'root'
server_ip_addr = '10.194.78.117'

loginPassword = '123456'


def main():
    cmd = "ssh -x -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l {} {}".format(username, server_ip_addr)
    t_spwan = pexpect.spawn(cmd, encoding='utf-8')
    t_spwan.logfile_read = sys.stdout
    t_spwan.expect("#", 30)

    t_spwan.sendline("")
    t_spwan.expect('#', 30)
    t_spwan.sendline("pwd")
    t_spwan.expect('#', 30)

    t_spwan.sendline("ls")
    t_spwan.expect('#', 30)

    t_spwan.sendline('exit')
    t_spwan.close()
    t_spwan.logfile_read = sys.stdout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Below is the code output：

```
root@SSL-SAP:/home/test/Templates# python3 first.py
ONIE:~ #
ONIE:~ # pwd
/root
ONIE:~ # ls
al_tool          diag             sdk              smartctl.tar.xz
al_tool.tar.xz   driver           smartctl
ONIE:~ # root@SSL-SAP:/home/test/Templates#
root@SSL-SAP:/home/test/Templates#
```

Thanks in advance！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know how to display the results on the terminal and how to redirect the results to a file, but I don’t know how to implement these two features at the same time.

If you want to save information from `stdout` in file (like `cmd > output`) but show `stdout` at the same time, you may use `tee`

[tee man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html)

```
$ ls -l | tee -a output.txt
# stdout displayed at the screen
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Aug  4 13:12 1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Aug  4 13:12 2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Aug  4 13:12 3

$ cat output.txt
# here we can see same info as stdout
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Aug  4 13:12 1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Aug  4 13:12 2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Aug  4 13:12 3
```

In your case command will be look like `first.py | tee -a output.txt` or `python3 first.py | tee -a output.txt`

Comment: This method is simple and effective, it's really inspired me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another answer from the internet

```
import pexpect, sys

class MutliIO:
    def __init__(self, *fds):
        self.fds = fds

    def write(self, data):
        for fd in self.fds:
            fd.write(data)

    def flush(self):
        for fd in self.fds:
            fd.flush()

logfile = open('pexpect.log', 'w')

child = pexpect.spawnu('python3')
child.logfile_read = MutliIO(sys.stdout, logfile)

child.expect('>>> ')

child.sendline('print("Hello, world.")')
child.expect('>>> ')

child.sendline('exit()')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
child.wait()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).